# Определить четное ли число

Tags: c#

Даны числа: 21,23,25,27,29.

Мой код выдает что они четные, а если ввести 35, то нечетное.

Помогите решить проблему.

```
int x;
x = Console.Read();
if ((x % 2) == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("chentoe");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("nechentoe");
}
```

Comment: Читайте внимательно описание метода Read.

Answer (score 8):

Вы делаете неправильно. Чтобы прочитать число с консоли, метод `Console.Read` не подходит, он возвращает лишь *код одного символа*.

Вам нужно считать всю строку при помощи `Console.ReadLine`, и распарсить её в число при помощи `int.Parse` или `int.TryParse` (предпочтительнее).

(Поскольку задание явно учебное, код не даю.)

Comment: Ну ты не прав только перешел из java к c# и не совсем понял куда вставить int.Parse и int.TryParse желательно можете сказать как их вставить

Comment: Не, если я сделаю задание за вас, вы точно ничему не научитесь. Посмотрите в документацию к `int.Parse`, что у этой функции на входе и что на выходе. Там всё просто, честно!

Comment: ну я попробую,и вы правы лучше я сделаю пробу ошибок но сам пойму как это работает

Comment: @VladD, как вариант еще можно предложить метод `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Ага, или так.

Answer (score -1):

```
        Start:
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((x % 2) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("chentoe");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nechentoe");
        }
        goto Start;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а зачем нужно было добавлять `goto Start`?  есть другие _стандартные_ способы записи бесконечного цикла.